# Show records with the same Id when they are on same stage and status

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on project where I need to show records from my database Where the Equipment needs to have the same status and stage:
For example here is my table:

```
EquipmentID      StatusID      StageID
1                2              2
1                1              2
2                2              2
2                2              2
```

The results should be like this:

```
EquipmentID      StatusID      StageID
2                2              2
2                2              2
```

I have tried doing it like this

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Table
WHERE   StageID  = 2
AND     StatusID = 2
```

but its not what I need

Comment: Add the rows (3,3,3) and (4,5,6) to your sample data, and adjust the result as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not formally articulate this, but it sounds like you want to return all equipment groups whose records *all* have matching `StatusID` and `StageID`.  This translates closely to the query below, which aggregates over equipment groups and performs this check.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT EquipmentID
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY EquipmentID
    HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN StatusID <> StageID THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
) t2
    ON t1.EquipmentID = t2.EquipmentID
WHERE
    t1.StageID = 2 AND t1.StatusID = 2
```

Comment: Yes, I want to group the equipment when they have both status and stage equal to 2 .. I have tried yours code but it should me all the results including the ones i want

Comment: I added WHERE by the end to set the values of stage and status and its working fine .. thank you so much

Comment: For sure, if you don't mind just add the `WHERE StageID= 2 AND StatusID = 2 ` to make it the 100% correct answer. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select with same EquipmentID, StageID and StatusID you can just use equal comparisons between them.

```
SELECT  *
    FROM    Table
    WHERE   StageID  = StatusID AND EquipmentID = StatusID;
```

Comment: Look at the expected output.  Do you see the first record there?  I agree that the language used might seem to imply your answer though.

Comment: So you want all of them to be equal. Edited the answer.